# Unable to run startup script when creating instance on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a simple startup script which looks like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y ruby-full ruby-bundler build-essential
```

And create VM instance on GCP like so:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create test-app --boot-disk-size=10GB --image-family ubuntu-1604-lts --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud --machine-type=g1-small --zone europe-west1-b --tags test-server --restart-on-failure --metadata-from-file startup-script=startup.sh
```

My `startup.sh` is executable. I set its rights like so:

```
$ chmod +x startup.sh
```

When however I enter the shell of my newly created instance and check bundler:

```
test-app:~$ bundle -v
```

I get these messages:

> The program 'bundle' is currently not installed...

So, what is wrong with that and how can I fix it? PS. If I run all my commands just from inside the instance shell, it's all ok, so there is some problem with using startup script on GCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with your use case, But the bundle package was installed without making any changes.

Output: 
`bundle -v
Bundler version 1.11.2`

You can check VM serial console log output to verify if start-up script ran. Check the VM instance to verify if the package is installed using the commands below:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep -i bundle
sudo egrep bundle /var/log/dpkg.log
```

In addition, check the `gem list bundle`